# Styling <hr> tag in css

Tags: html, css

I want to Blur my hr in css but I have some difficulties. 
Please help or advise....

```
hr {
clear:both;
margin-bottom: 0px;
border: 0;
height: 2px;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.75), rgba(0,0,0,0));
box-shadow: inset 0px -5px -20px -60px #000;
}
```

Comment: Define "difficulties"

Comment: your code seems to work OK? what's wrong?

Comment: use css pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` to achieve this

Comment: Here is a exmaple http://www.invented4kids.com/home/ @KingKing. I want mine hr exactly like the one on from the site. But im really inexperienced so i don't know where to begin.

Comment: They've used [an image](http://www.invented4kids.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/homeContentSplitter.png), if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple backgrounds feature, you need to specify the first background (the behind one) which is gradiented vertically (looks like a shadow) while the second backgrournd (the front one) is gradiented horizontally (looks like fading):

```
hr {
 clear:both;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 border: 0;
 height: 6px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent, white), 
                   linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 150%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent, white), 
                   -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 150%);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to right, white, transparent, white), 
                   -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0,0,0,0.55) 150%);  
}
```

Note that we used the color `white` as the background of the parent, currently this solution works only if the parent has a solid background, otherwise the color `white` will be distinct and shows off ugly.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/z7du5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, the best way to solve your problem without much difficulties is forgetting the idea of use the `hr` tag and use a **PNG** instead of.

*Example:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/r116W.png

So, put a image like this one in a `img` tag **OR** `div` tag as `background-image:`.
**NOTE:** If you put the "hr image" in a `div` tag you only need to adjust the height and set the width to 100% (or dimension you want), because it will repeat horizontally.

Comment: using image of course has its own advantage however CSS is always a lightweight and preferred way (save the bandwidth), you can easily change the color and many other features without redesigning the image.